# How to read xlsx files with Pandas.read_excel, openpyxl (without manually re-saving files)?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsx

I am reading excel 'xlsx' files using openpyxl. It works with most files but it fails with some.

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

The file in question, let's call it `file1`, can't be read properly, this is what it returns:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file1.xlsx, engine='openpyxl') 

# OUTPUT
# Empty DataFrame
# Columns: [column 1]   <- It does read the first column
# Index: []
```

When I manually open said file with excel and simply re-save it (same name, same everything), it works:

```
df = pd.read_excel(resaved_file1.xlsx, engine='openpyxl') 

# OUTPUT
# column 1     ...                   column 70
# 0     12     ...                      hidden
# 1     13     ...                      hidden
# 2     15     ...                      hidden
# 3    111     ...                   something
# 4    213     ...                private_data

# [5 rows x 70 columns]
```

The issue I have is that it is supposed to be an automated process, so I will not be able to open thousands of files and manually modify them.

I can not use the outdated xlrd=1.2.0 since it is unsafe, especially for my purpose. xlrd devs are literally shouting not to use the old version since it's busted. For those who don't know, xlrd=2.x.x does not support xlsx files anymore.

Also, I am sorry as I am not allowed to show you the actual data since it is very sensitive.

One possibility: We could use command lines to run excel, open all files and resave all files. The issue I have with this process is that I can't differentiate between "corrupted" files and good files, so I would have to apply this process to everything, slowing down the entire system. If it is the only solution, I'll take it, as a last resort.

TL;DR Microsoft is having a lot of fun with its closed source software and it's not safe to use.

Versions:

- Python 3.8.3
- xlrd 2.1.0
- openpyxl 3.0.4

Comment: how is the source file generated ?

Comment: No idea. Many files generated by different entities out of my control. I will try my best to get whatever I can about it. Those files are generated automatically.

Comment: I think your issue is more upstream, either the source file is not being generated correctly or you have a specific environment problem, did you try spinning up a new virtual env to test?

Comment: You could try to convert the `xlsx` files [to `csv`](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv) prior to loading them in `pandas`.

Comment: @RJ Adriansen Ok. Do you have a prefered module you want me to use to convert to csv?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Confirmed! I just tried with a new venv and it worked! Pandas 3.8.8, pandas 1.2.3, openpyxl 3.0.7. Maybe it's the new version of openpyxl that works better.